# Launch app automatically Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-8.1-universal

I want to launch my windows phone app automatically whenever the device gets active after inactivity or device is restarted. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: in general this is not possible

Comment: This is not possible , please refer the application life cycle here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle

Answer (score 1):

I donot think there is a way to Resume the application from **Suspended** state **AUTOMATICALLY**. Windows phone doesnt provide any mechanism to relaunch the app on the conditions you specified.

when an app is suspended , The OS tries to save the data first and then Kill the app if the app is not resumed within a specific period of time. So what you can necessarily do is to relaunch the application yourself and can restore the state where you left it.